# How to store arbitrary data inside a png file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, png

I'm making a UserScript in TypeScript that allows someone to download a specific `<canvas>` as a `.png` file. This `<canvas>` is an outfit in a dress-up game. I want to include a JSON blob within the exported `.png` so that users can later import this `.png` and access the outfit's data.

The data insertion should be non-destructive (no steganography).

How do I insert arbitrary data in a PNG file in JavaScript?

Comment: Do you mean metadata? Or would you like to generate images in invalid format? Maybe encode data in some pixels (they will be visible)? Or how else do you want to encode data in a picture? And why do you want to do this (what data do you want to store; maybe there's a better way)?

Comment: It can't be an invalid format because I need to show the initial `<canvas>` and it can't be destructive/steganography because I need to preserve the original `<canvas>`. Both of these requirements are inside the question.

Comment: I got those, and that's why I'm asking: how did you imagine storing that extra data? Btw, we can help more easily if we know **what** data do you want to store and **why**, so we may propose alternatives to what you have thought out.

Comment: It's a json blob. The canvas is an outfit in a dress up game, which I'm exporting in a PNG and I can also export the outfit's data as `.json`. Users are a bit scared of `.json` files and don't understand why importing the image doesn't import the outfit. They basically want the screenshot of the outfit to also contain the data of the outfit so they can import the image directly later. Misusing a metadata field is fair, if it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I thought I'd share my thoughts in case anyone comes across a similar issue.

I believe saving a canvas essentially works through base 64 encoding the image data, so I don't think there will be a way to do exactly what you want.

You could send the data to a server and attach any metadata you want there. I believe the PNG format supports arbitrary metadata.

However, you could also encode the data in a "non-destructive" way by using the RGB channels of transparent pixels, assuming there are any. Since they are transparent, the RGB values won't matter.

If you don't have enough space there are a few options:

- Compress/reduce the data you want to save
- Increase the resolution, either by scaling or adding a border of transparent pixels
- Store the information on a server instead of encoding the full data, then just encode a reference ID and retrieve it with an ajax request.

Additionally, if you only use the least significant bits of non-transparent pixels, you can encode more data in a way that won't significantly reduce the quality of the image. You could also reduce degradation by only touching pixels in a checkerboard/dithered pattern.